# Messenger bot does not receive postbacks

Tags: postback, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Out of nowhere my bot stopped receiving post-backs from Messenger.
Yes, I have **messaging_postbacks** ticked in the event list. The bot receives text messages just fine.

Heroku logs show that when I press a button in the chat, the webhook is not called at all, so it's not a bug in the code. Was there some kind of recent change to the post-backs perhaps?

Comment: Can you post the code for the template that is using the postback button?

Comment: @amuramoto the postbacks events are currently in the persistent menu, if they are written incorrectly, Facebook won't allow to put the menu up

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/144222573036958/